# Python: Write colored text in file

Tags: python

I want to write a file containing some arithmetic problems for my little child. I want to have some coloring, so that he can easily make the difference between plus and minus.
This worked for me very well. Unfortunately, only in a terminal.

```
import random as rd
from termcolor import colored

N = 10
MAX = 100
f = open("math.txt", "w")


def get_random_str():

    a = rd.randint(1, MAX)
    b = rd.randint(1, MAX)

    if a < MAX*0.4:
        string = "%3d "%a + str(colored('+', 'blue')) + " %d = \n"%(b)

    else:
        if a>b:
            string = "%3d "%a + str(colored('-', 'red')) + " %d = \n"%(b)

        else:
            string = "%3d "%a + str(colored('-', 'red')) + " %d = \n"%(b)

    return string
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------

for i in range(1,N):
    print i, get_random_str()
```

When I try to write the output in a file, of course I just get  the color codes e.g. "[34m+[0m" instead of a red "-" and a blue "+".

Any idea how to solve this task?

Comment: Wait... Do you want to paint some characters in **file**?

Comment: I think this is not a Python related. It is the program you view the file that matters. I think you can use a html file, write the html to the file using Python.

Comment: Maybe there is a need in coloring of `cat file` in Terminal? That's an ambiguous question.

Comment: Just a suggestion: Wouldn't HTML/JavaScript be a simpler choice of tools for this sort of thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could check out [Pygments](http://pygments.org/docs/quickstart/) with any suitable [lexer](http://pygments.org/docs/lexers/) and a [TerminalFormatter](http://pygments.org/docs/formatters/).

E.g. the following code:

```
import sys
from pygments import highlight
from pygments.formatters.terminal import TerminalFormatter
from pygments.lexer import RegexLexer
from pygments.token import Token


class ArithmeticLexer(RegexLexer):
    tokens = {
        'root': [
            (r'[ \n]', Token.Whitespace),
            (r'\d+', Token.Number),
            (r'\+', Token.Plus),
            (r'-', Token.Minus),
            (r'\*', Token.Multiply),
            (r'/', Token.Division),
        ]
    }

COLOR_SCHEME = {
    Token.Whitespace: ('', ''),
    Token.Number: ('darkgreen', 'green'),
    Token.Plus: ('darkred', 'red'),
    Token.Minus: ('darkblue', 'blue'),
    Token.Multiply: ('darkyellow', 'yellow'),
    Token.Division: ('brown', 'fushia'),
}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as f:
        for line in f:
            line = highlight(line, ArithmeticLexer(), TerminalFormatter(colorscheme=COLOR_SCHEME))
            print line.strip()
```

Gives:

[image]

When ran using file with given contents. The usage is `<script_name> <input_file_name>`.

The [colors' reference](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/src/7304e4759ae65343d89a51359ca538912519cc31/pygments/console.py?at=default#cl-25). The colors in `COLOR_SCHEME` are tuples of `(lightscheme, darkscheme)`. By defaults `TerminalFormatter` uses `lightscheme`.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but this works only for terminals, right?

Comment: Yes, depends on where you want your formatting to be applied you should pick an appriopriate formatter from the list i've referenced to. If you choose different formatter, the script will output strings formatted according to desired format, i.e. HTML document etc.

Answer (score 3):

This requires the program that you are using to view the files to support ANSI escape sequences. This is possible, for example, in GNU/Linux with `less -R`.

Comment: It's not so much that `less` supports ANSI escape sequences, it's that Terminal does, so they work when `less` send its output to it.

Comment: You are right. I think it is a problem related to the editor rather than to python. I solved it using `xlwt` and just produce an excel-file.

Comment: @martineau, it's certainly important that `less` supports sending the raw escape characters; it's for that reason if you simply `cat` the file or use `less` without the `-R` switch, you'll just see the escape characters. The terminal requires that they be output in their raw form rather than as the literal characters (`/`, `0`, `3`, `3`, etc.), and most text editors / pagers won't do that unless you specify it.

Answer (score 2):

## Use CSI colour escape sequences

CSI stands for [Control Sequence Introducer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Sequence_elements). Here is a list with [more CSI colours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors).

```
csi    = '\x1B['
red    = csi + '31;1m'
yellow = csi + '33;1m'
end    = csi + '0m'

print('Here is a %sred%s word and one in %syellow!%s' % (red, end, yellow, end))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to write to an RTF file instead of a plain text file. This way you can write text and open in a word processor with full color and highlights

Or just write to an HTML file.